# 3D Space Required to Define a 2D Rotation

Tags: geometry

There are 2D transforms that can be defined in the same way that higher dimensions like translate and scale. However, it seems like rotations cannot be defined the same way as rotations in higher dimensions.

For example in 3D a rotation is defined by a 3D Point, 3D Vector, and Angle. In 2D, the vector requires a higher dimension.

Is there a way to consistently define a rotation while remaining in the same dimensionality?

Comment: Perhaps it could be defined with a Point, Plane, and Angle. Or, just a point and rotation matrix.

Comment: Rotations are generalized as orthonormal matrices in higher dimensions

Comment: Who says you need a vector in 2D, really?

Comment: @IvanNeretin exactly, but what about nD

Comment: In nD a vector won't suffice.

Comment: Matches what user721481 said